# How to do multiple density plots in plotnine

Tags: density-plot, plotnine

I'm having trouble finding useful documentation or examples of doing multiple density plots in plotnine.

I've tried several approaches but still get an error.

```
p      = (ggplot(data=gg,aes(x='u',color='x')) + geom_density()  
print(p)
```

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

I've checked the data types on the dataframe.  They are a series from original numpy arrays.

Comment: [Examples](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/blob/master/plotnine/tests/test_geom_density.py) of geom_density from the tests.

Comment: Thanks.  I ran the code and it worked.  I then tried a few things that worked in R and with an idea that came from an error message I found an even simpler approach that worked.  If I could make a suggestion, a gallery of basic plot examples might be much more useful than the advanced ones for most people. I could post the code it you would like.  -- Thanks again